# Execution of script php concerning Linphonecsh problematic from browser

Tags: php, mozilla, linphone

I did a script in php which allow me voip calls: it uses a daemon virtual phone called linphonecsh, and I have to call another virtual phone in my smartphone. 
When I execute my script from terminal, all is OK. I can execute it lots of time and the communication is good.

Instead, if I execute the script from browser, it happens a strange thing: the first time all is ok, but if I try to execute again the script it happens nothing. I must restart my virtual machine (with ubuntu) to execute the script a second time from browser.

I tried to cancel all the browser cache between two execution but I've not improved the result. The result is the same for Mozilla and Crhomium. This is the script:

```
<?php
$output1=shell_exec ("linphonecsh init");
sleep(1);
echo "INIT done<br>";
$output2=shell_exec ("linphonecsh register --host sip:sip.linphone.org --username        
sip:matpc --password 123123");
sleep(2);
echo "REGISTRATION done<br>";
$a= shell_exec("linphonecsh status register");
echo $a;
echo "<br>";
sleep(1);
$output=shell_exec ("linphonecsh dial sip:mat99@sip.linphone.org");
echo $output;
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I solved: 
before a new executing, lauch: sudo pkill linphonec from terminal